# How is a recursive prime number checker written in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, primes

I'm very new to Haskell (and functional programming in general), and I'm trying some basic exercises to try to get an understanding of the language. I'm writing a "naive" prime number checker that divides each number under the input to check if there is any remainder. The only constructs I've learned so far are comprehension lists and recursive functions, so I'm constrained to that. Here's what I'm trying:

```
isprime 1 = False
isprime 2 = True
isprime n = isprimerec n (n-1)

isprimerec _ 1 = False
isprimerec n t = if (n `rem` t) == 0 then False else isprimerec n (n-1)
```

The intention is that the user would use `isprime n`. Then `isprime` would use `isprimerec` to determine if the number is prime. It's a pretty round-about way of doing it, but I don't know any other way with my limited knowledge of Haskell.

Here's what happens when I try this:

```
isprimerec 10 9
```

Runs forever. I have to use Ctrl+C to stop it.

```
isprimerec 10 5
```

Returns False. The `else` part is never evaluated, so the function never calls itself.

I'm not sure why this is happening. Also, is this anywhere near close to how a Haskell programmer would approach this problem? (And I don't mean checking primality, I know this isn't the way to do it. I'm just doing it this way as an exercise).

Comment: You can replace `isprime n = isprimerec n (n-1)` with `isprime n = isprimerec n (n \`div\` 2)` since n will not be divisible by any number greater than n/2

Comment: @CarlosLópez-Camey I was thinking about doing that, but I was afraid that it would return a floating point number instead of an integer. Does `div` only return integers then?

Comment: Yes, the type of `div` is `Integral a => a -> a -> a` and there are only two instances of `Integral` in the Prelude: `Integer` and `Int` (this can be checked with `:i Integral` in ghci)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
isprimerec n t = if (n `rem` t) == 0 then False else isprimerec n (n-1)
```

You use `(n - 1)` as the second argument where it should be `(t - 1)`.  A further point, I think you want the `isprimerec _ 1` case `= True`.

As to your more general question of whether or not this is idiomatic, I think you're on the right track.  `ghci` has a decent command line debugger.  I found this by putting your code in a file, loading it, and then issuing the command `:break isprimerec`.  I then called your function and stepped through it with `:step`.

Answer (score 6):

Your bug is a simple typo; at the end of `isprimerec`, your second parameter becomes `n-1` instead of `t-1`.  But that aside, the function isn't quite idiomatic.  Here's the first pass of how I would write it:

```
isPrime :: (Ord a, Integral a) => a -> Bool
isPrime n | abs n <= 1 = False
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime n = go $ abs n - 1
  where go 1 = False
        go t = (n `rem` t /= 0) && go (t-1)
```

(I might call `go` something like `checkDivisors`, but `go` is idiomatic for a loop.)  Note that this exposes the bug in your code: once `go` is local to `isPrime`, you don't need to pass `n` around, and so it becomes clearer that recursing on it is incorrect.  The changes I made were, in rough order of importance:

1. I made `isprimerec` a local function.  Nobody else would need to call it, and we lose the extra parameter.
2. I made the function total.  There's no reason to fail on `0`, and not really any reason to fail for negative numbers.  (Technically speaking, *p* is prime if and only if -*p* is prime.)
3. I added a type signature.  It's a good habit to get into.  Using `Integer -> Bool`, or even `Int -> Bool`, would also have been reasonable.
4. I switched to interCaps instead of alllowercase.  Just formatting, but it's customary.

Except I'd probably make things terser.  Manual recursion is usually unnecessary in Haskell, and if we get rid of that entirely, your bug becomes impossible.  Your function checks that all the numbers from `2` to `n-1` don't divide `n`, so we can express that directly:

```
isPrime :: (Ord a, Integral a) => a -> Bool
isPrime n | abs n <= 1 = False
          | otherwise  = all ((/= 0) . (n `rem`)) [2 .. abs n - 1]
```

You could write this on one line as

```
isPrime :: (Ord a, Integral a) => a -> Bool
isPrime n = abs n > 1 && all ((/= 0) . (n `rem`)) [2 .. abs n - 1]
```

but I wouldn't be surprised to see either of these last two implementations.  And as I said, the nice thing about these implementations is that your typo isn't possible to make in these representations: the `t` is hidden inside the definition of `all`, and so you can't accidentally give it the wrong value.

Comment: One final thought: with the [`-XViewPatterns`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#view-patterns) language extension, you can write `isPrime (abs -> n) = n > 1 && ...`, which is *arguably* cleaner (if you like that language extension).

Answer (score 3):

Your `else` branch is broken since it calls `isprimerec n (n-1)` every time. You probably ought to write `isprimerec n (t-1)` instead to have it count down.

You could also use a higher-order function `all` to make this a lot simpler.

```
isprime 1 = False
isprime n = all (\t -> n `rem` t /= 0) [2..(n-1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

So OK, you've got the two bugs: your

```
isprimerec _ 1 = False
isprimerec n t = if (n `rem` t) == 0 then False else isprimerec n (n-1)
```

should have been

```
isprimerec _ 1 = True
isprimerec n t = if (n `rem` t) == 0 then False else isprimerec n (t-1)
```

or, with list comprehension,

```
isprime n = n>1 && and [ rem n t /= 0 | t <- [n-1,n-2..2] ]
```

(*Internalize* that extra parameter *`t`*, it was a technicality anyway! -- A-ha, but what's that `and`, you ask? It's just like this recursive function, `foldr (&&) True :: [Bool] -> Bool`.)

But now a major *algorithmic* drawback becomes *visually* apparent: we test in the *wrong* order. It will be faster if we test in ascending order:

```
isprime n = n>1 && and [ rem n t /= 0 | t <- [2..n-1] ]
```

or even much faster yet if we stop at the `sqrt`,

```
isprime n = n>1 && and [ rem n t /= 0 | t <- [2..q] ]
   where  q = floor (sqrt (fromIntegral n))
```

or test only by *odds*, after the *2* (why test by *6*, if we've tested by *2* already?):

```
isprime n = n>1 && and [ rem n t /= 0 | t <- 2:[3,5..q] ]
   where  q = floor (sqrt (fromIntegral n))
```

or just by *primes* (why test by *9*, if we've tested by *3* already?):

```
isprime n = n>1 && and [ rem n t /= 0 | t <- takeWhile ((<= n).(^2)) primes ]
primes = 2 : filter isprime [3..]
```

And why test the *evens* when filtering the primes through - isn't it better to not generate them in the first place?

```
primes = 2 : filter isprime [3,5..]
```

But `isprime` always tests division by *2* -- yet we feed it only the odd numbers; so,

```
primes = 2 : 3 : filter (noDivs (drop 1 primes)) [5,7..]
noDivs factors n = and [ rem n t /= 0 | t <- takeWhile ((<= n).(^2)) factors ]
```

And why generate the multiples of *3* (i.e. `[9,15 ..] == map (3*) [3,5..]`), only to test and remove them later? --

```
{-       [5,7..]
    ==   [j+i | i<-[0,2..], j<-[5]]                 -- loop unrolling, 3x:
    ==   [j+i | i<-[0,6..], j<-[5,7,9]]
    == 5:[j+i | i<-[0,6..], j<-[7,9,11]]            
    == 5:[7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43, ...
    \\   [  9,      15,      21,      27,      33,      39,       ...
    ==   [j+i | i<-[0,6..], j<-[  9   ]]
-}
primes = 2:3:5: filter (noDivs (drop 2 primes)) 
         [j+i | i<-[0,6..], j<-[7,  11]]
```

We can skip over the multiples of *5* in advance as well <sub>*(as another step in the [Euler's sieve](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Unbounded_Euler.27s_sieve), `` euler (x:xs) = x : euler (xs `minus` map (x*) (x:xs)) ``):*</sub>

```
--       [j+i | i<-[0, 6..], j<-[7, 11]]            -- loop unrolling, 5x:
--  == 7:[j+i | i<-[0,30..], j<-[11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35,37]]
--  \\   [j+i | i<-[0,30..], j<-[               25,      35   ]]

primes = 2:3:5:7: filter (noDivs (drop 3 primes)) 
         [j+i | i<-[0,30..], j<-[11,13,17,19,23,   29,31,   37]]
```

... but that's already going [far enough, for now](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Wheeled_list_representation).

Comment: On what basis are the values for `i` and `j` in the last two examples chosen?

Comment: @is7s we start with odds, `[5,7..] == [j+i | i<-[0,2..], j<-[5]] == [j+i | i<-[0,6..], j<-[5,7,9]]`. the last is same as `5:[j+i | i<-[0,6..], j<-[7,9,11]]`. `5` is taken away; then `9` in thrown out as it generates the multiples of 3, being a multiple of 3 itself. were left with `[j+i | i<-[0,6..], j<-[7,11]]` then. this actually follows the sieve of Euler, ``eulers (x:xs) = x:(xs `minus` map(x*) (x:xs))``, more at [haskellwiki page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Wheeled_list_representation).

Comment: @is7s similarly for the next step, from `[j+i | i<-[0,6..], j<-[7,11]]` we go by five "segments/wheel-lengths" to `[j+i | i<-[0,30..], j<-[7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35]]`, then remove `25,35` from the generating seed values. `7` is picked, so `37` comes in instead.

Comment: you're welcome. :) that's just another way to avoid `concat`. List comprehensions are much more *visual*.